# Learning to build tumblr themes, having trouble centering - actually just made a big mess in general

Tags: css

Had it working nicely - then managed to mess it up trying to take out the deprecated center tags by adding an outside container. I've tried to use relative positioning, auto margins, 50% margins all the things for centering that I've found suggested. I think probably the real problem is that I set one thing wrong and so no matter what I do elsewhere it won't work. Obviously now it is a complete cluster. Really looking to learn (this is the first thing I've tried to build from scratch) so didn't want to just copy an example of a working theme - wanted to figure out what is wrong with this one. Any advice appreciated.

[calliopecompendium.tumblr.com](http://calliopecompendium.tumblr.com)

CSS

```
    <style type="text/css">
        /*major elements*/
            body {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            background:{color:Background}url('{image:Background}');
            color: {color:Body text};
            font-family: {font:Body};
            font-size: {text:Font size};
            }
         article {
            margin: {text:Post margin};
            padding: 2%;
            width: 20%;
            }
        a {
            color: {color:Body links};
            text-decoration: none;
            }
        iframe, img, embed, object, video {
            padding: 5%;
            max-width: 90%;
            overflow:hidden;
            }
        img {
            height: auto;
            width: auto;
            }
    /*id*/
    /*containers*/
        #container{
            width:1200px;
            position:fixed;
            }
        #header{
            width:1000px;
            position:relative;
            }
        #content{
            width:1000px;
            position:relative;
            }
        #tags, nav ul, .chat ul {
            list-style: none;
            list-style-image: none;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 2px;
            }
    /*masthead*/
        #masthead {
            background:  url('{image:Masthead}');
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            height:350px;
            }
        #masthead img {
            display: block;
            position:absolute;
            top:20px;
            }
        #masthead p {
            position:absolute;
            top:300px;
            }
    /*menu*/
        #menu {
            position:relative
            top: 0px;
            background-color:{color:Masthead menu};
            width:1000px;
            height:36px;
            list-style:none;
            }
        #menu li {
            display: inline;
            }
       #menu li a {
            display: block;
            padding: 10px;
            text-decoration: none;
            font-weight: bold;
            color: #fcebb6;
            }
        #menu li a:hover {
            background-color: #f7d11f;
            color: #f08818;
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got a lot of problems on that page, far too many to debug here. But, to start a website with a container that's in the center you would do the following:

```
.container { width: 960px; margin: 0 auto; }
```

I would recommend going back over the basics of CSS on CodeAcademy, that would solve a lot of your problems.